# Pentaho date type problems

Tags: excel, csv, pentaho

I've got a CSV-file with header as first row:

1;2;Q1;Q2;Q3;Q4;Avd

Pressretur;Intäkt Pressretur; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0;320
Lej RP;Intäkt Lejhantering; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0;320
Lej FTI;Intäkt Lejhantering (FTI); 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0;320
Kartong FTI;Intäkt Kartong FTI; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0;320
Plast Fti;Intäkt Plast FTI; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0; 0,0;320

I try to convert it to Excel-file with the Excel Output but it fails
whatever configuration I try.

It seems to me as it is a DATA TYPE error. When I set up the CSV Import
I've tried with both NONE and NUMBER as type for the COL3-7 fields from the CSV but when data shall be written to Excel it ends up with a NullpointerException.
If I just go for the two first COLUMNS it works but when I try to add the number COLUMNS it fails.

What can be wrong?

Comment: How are you doing so? You can import to Excel and do Data --> [Text to Columns](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html), no?

Comment: Have you tried changing the delimiter in the csv input ?? Also put the exact error in the question above. it will be easier to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Can you "Preview" the data in your Input step (or send it to a Dummy Step or a Text Output, instead of Excel Output)?  If you cannot, the problem lies with your Input, not with your Output.

2) You are using semicolon as a delimiter and comma as a decimal - which is fine - just make sure your PDI configuration and/or step parameters are consistent with that.

Comment: I think my PDI verision is pretty unstable and now it works for me. Sometimes I need to restart Pentaho in Pentaho/Kettle and then it works.